# using python crypto(aes),with same str needed tobe decrypto, the second time will report an error

Tags: python, encryption, aes

```
PADDING = '\0'
# PADDING = ' '
pad_it = lambda s: s + (16 - len(s) % 16) * PADDING
generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

def encrypt(data):
    crypt = generator.encrypt(pad_it(data))
    result = base64.b64encode(crypt)
    return result

def decrypt(data):
    print base64.b64decode(data)
    return generator.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data))
```

My code is above. The `decrypt` function throws an error:

```
    generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return generator.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data))
```

Every the second time where is an error, weird!
Here is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Why? And How do I fix it?

Comment: I made a large reformat to make your post make a little more sense, but I don't understand "Every the second time where is an error."

Comment: thanks Adam Smith alot

Answer (score -1):

generator = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

that is problem, when using aes, we need to instance a new generator when encrypt or decrypt

Comment: You could expand on *why* this is needed (the fact that when decrypting it starts of iv and generates a stream of blocks to be used to decrypt the encrypted blocks. If you don't match the encrypted block with the corresponding block in the sequence it doesn't work...)